# Как получить порядковый номер для каждой операции подставления в функцию

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть список `lists` который попадает в функцию `first(list)`. Как теперь получить порядковый номер для каждой операции подставления значений из списка `lists` в переменную `hw`. Т.е. получить на выходе ответ:

```py
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

```py
def first(list):

    hw = "Hello," + " " + list

    print(hw)

lists = ["world! (1)", "world! (2)", "world! (3)", "world! (4)", "world! (5)", "world! (6)"]

for list in lists:
    first(list)
```

Comment: Нужно вытащить номер из значения строки или нужно счетчиком считать количество раз вызова `first`?

Comment: @gil9red, счетчиком

Comment: Неудачный у вас пример входных данных, сбили с толку. Хотя сам виноват, что невнимательно вчитался :) Почему бы вам просто не итерировать индексами список? Например: `for i, value in enumerate(lists, 1): first(value) print(i)` или `for i in range(len(lists)): value = lists[i] first(value) print(i + 1)`. Можете объяснить для чего вам это понадобилось? Если есть задание, то добавьте в вопрос.

Comment: @gil9red, спасибо большое! `for i in range(len(lists)): value = lists[i] first(value) print(i + 1)` способ помог

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для получения порядка элементов списка:

```
def first(list):
    hw = "Hello," + " " + list
    print(hw)

lists = ["world! (1)", "world! (2)", "world! (3)", "world! (4)", "world! (5)", "world! (6)"]
```

используйте `enumerate`:

```
for i, value in enumerate(lists, 1):
    first(value)
    print(i)
```

или `range`:

```
for i in range(len(lists)):
    value = lists[i]
    first(value)
    print(i + 1)
```